# How to access Gitlab Package Registry from CI/CD Dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, cicd

I set up a `Package Registry` in `gitlab` that contains a `my-commons.jar`, making use of it in my project as follows:

`pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.my-company.com/api/v4/projects/295/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This also requires the use of a `Private-Token` for access, that is placed into the `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>MY_TOKEN</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

This works fine locally.

Question: how can I reuse this in a docker file, and especially when it comes to the gitlab `CI/CD` pipeline. Should I commit a custom `settings.xml` to gitlab that includes the private token, so that the gitlab pipeline knows how to access the package repository?

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM $BUILD_IMAGE as dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN mvn package
#RUN mvn package private_settings.xml #is that reasonable?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as an environment variable.
`settings.xml`

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>${MY_TOKEN}</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM $BUILD_IMAGE as dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
COPY settings.xml settings.xml

ARG MY_TOKEN

RUN mvn package
RUN mvn package -s settings.xml
```

Then, use `docker build`

```
docker build --build-arg MY_TOKEN=$MY_TOKEN -t image-name:tag .
```

`docker` will get $MY_TOKEN from env of OS.

Comment: And this would inject the token into `env.*` namespace automatically??

Comment: Docker get env $MY_TOKEN in command `docker build` from env of OS.

Comment: Which OS (windows, linux, macOS) do you use?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: For my it was sufficient to simply set the `ARG MY_TOKEN` statement. I edited your answer to show the correct solution for this case. Moreover, I think exposing a secret token as `ENV` variable is a security risk, thus using `ARG` should always be prefered.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the token into a gitlab variable like `$MAVEN_TOKEN`, then use `$MAVEN_TOKEN` in the `settings.xml` and commit the `settings.xml` to the repository.